# add in Pandas Series without sorting

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, addition, series

I want to add two Series in Pandas and I use add() function to do this like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.Series([35000,71000,16000,5000],index=['Ohio','Texas','Oregon','Utah'])
b = pd.Series([np.nan,71000,16000,35000],index=['California', 'Texas', 'Oregon', 'Ohio'])
print(a.add(b, fill_value=0))
```

It prints :

```
California         NaN
Ohio           70000.0
Oregon         32000.0
Texas         142000.0
Utah            5000.0
dtype: float64
```

This method sort my indexes But I don't want to

What can I do or What method can I use?

Comment: what would be the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expected output is unclear, but assuming you want to keep the exact index of `a`, you could do:

```
a.add(b.reindex_like(a), fill_value=0)
```

output:

```
Ohio       70000.0
Texas     142000.0
Oregon     32000.0
Utah        5000.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

If the indices don't matter, you could simply add the `values` of the series, eg

```
c = a.values + b.values
```

This returns a numpy array:

```
array([    nan, 142000.,  32000.,  40000.])
```

It seems like you may also want to fill in 0 for nans -- in which case, try this:

```
c = a.fillna(0).values + b.fillna(0).values
```